# Webpack/React.js: You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: typescript, webpack

> ERROR in ./productFlow/index.tsx 3:12 Module parse failed: Unexpected
>   token (3:12) File was processed with these loaders:  *
>   ./node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist/entry.js You may need an
>   additional loader to handle the result of these loaders. | import
>   React from 'react'; | export default props => {
>      return ( |       `<p>Compiled Successfully</p>` |     );

It appears to fail when it hits JSX code (in a .tsx file). Is at-loader not capable of handling this? I searched around for a react loader but the examples I saw were closer to my own:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const dotEnvWebpack = require("dotenv-webpack");
const path = require("path");

const webpackConfiguration = {
  entry : {
    productFlow : path.join(__dirname, "productFlow/index.tsx")
    , registrationFlow : path.join(__dirname, 'registrationFlow/index.tsx')
  }
  , output : {
    filename : "outputFiles/[name].output.js"
    , path : path.resolve(__dirname, "")
    , publicPath : '/'
  }
  , watch : true
  , watchOptions : { aggregateTimeout : 300 }
  , devtool : 'inline-source-map'
  , mode : "development"
  , devServer : {
    port: 3000
    , contentBase : path.join(__dirname, "devIndex.html")
    , hot : true
    , historyApiFallback : true
  }
  , plugins : [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new dotEnvWebpack
  ]
  , node : {
    fs: "empty" // for dotenv to work correctly
  }
  , resolve : { extensions : ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'] }
  , module : {
      rules : [{
        test : /\.tsx?$/
        , use : 'awesome-typescript-loader'
        , exclude : [/node_modules/, /outputFiles/]
      }]
  }
  , externals : {
      'react' : 'React'
      , 'react-dom' : 'ReactDOM'
  }
};

module.exports = webpackConfiguration;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was not a webpack issue, it was tsconfig relaxed. The loader recognized JSX after adding this line to tsconfig.json:

```
  "jsx": "react",
```